# How exactly works JMS queue (point to point message)?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jms, spring-jms

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and I have some doubt about how **JMS** works and about how Spring handle it.

So I know that the **JMS Core Components** are:

1. Message
2. Destination
3. Connection
4. Session
5. MessageProducer
6. MessageConsumer

From what I have understand a **Message** is what is send and shared with other entities (other products that have to consume this data) and a message can have differents shapes: **TextMessage**, **ObjectMessage**, **MapMessage**, **BytesMessage** and **StreamMessage**.

Ok, from what I understand the **Destination** component of the JMS Core Components defines who receives messages and the logic for dispatching messages.

So I know that I have 2 kinds of destinations that are:

1. **Queue:** that define a **point to point** message. From what I have understand I can have some **Message Producer** that put the generated messages into a queue and then I have some **MessageConsumer** that consume message. Each message can be consumed by a single **MessageConsumer**.

   Now my doubt is: a **MessageConsumer** consume message putted into the queue by a specific **MessageProducer** (there is something like a 1 to 1 relationship between **MessageConsumer** and **MessageProducer**) or a **MessageProducer** put an id related to the specific **MessageConsumer** that have to read the message that it put into the queue?

So for example, in the first case if I have 2 **MessageProducer** respectivelly named **Producer-1** and **Producer-2** I need to have 2 **MessageConsumer** named **Consumer-1** and **Consumer-2** where **Consumer-1** consume messages produced from **Producer-1** and **Consumer-2** consume messages produced from **Producer-2).

Instead in the second case the **Consumer-1** can consum messages produced by from both **Producer-1** and **Produer-2** because the **MessageProducer** put a message in the queue specifying who is the **MessageConsumer** that have to consume the message.

How exactly works? What is the correct logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I have 2 MessageProducer respectivelly named Producer-1 and
>   Producer-2 I need to have 2 MessageConsumer named Consumer-1 and
>   Consumer-2 where Consumer-1 consume messages produced from Producer-1
>   and Consumer-2 consume messages produced from **Producer-2).

Not really. The message consumer is connected to the queue and it will receive all messages that are put in the queue irrespective of the Producer. So if you have two producers that put a message each in the queue, it will be consumed by the single consumer connected to it.

If you wish to have messages produced by different producers targeted to specific consumers, you should use a concept known as 'message selectors'. To achieve this, Message producers should add 'headers' to the messages (system headers or custom ones) and then message listeners can specify that they receive messages that match a specific header.

Comment: Ok, so are you saying to me that the message contains something like an ID that specify what consumer have to read it? or what? What happens if I have 2 producers that put message in a queue and 2 consumers on the same queue?

Comment: No.  What I was saying is that if you need to have producer 1 deliver its message to consumer 1, producer 1 has to ** explicitly add an id to the message ** and consumer one has to specify that it listens only to messages that contain such an id (id is the message header). The message by default will not contain any ID. If you did not add any header that can be used as a message selector ** and ** there are 2 consumers connected to it, there is no guarantee who receives what. The only thing that is guaranteed is that the message will be delivered to exactly 1 consumer.